# Why AVRO for Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro

If Java can serialize anything when sending over the network. Why did they create a brand new framework for Kafka (AVRO) and not just serialize regular JSON ?

Comment: Since "they" did it, you should probably ask "them".

Comment: @ScottHunter  haha sure. But do i have a valid question? I am  new to kafka

Comment: If you aren't asking "them," you are asking for someone's opinion, which is *not* a valid question for this forum.

Comment: @ScottHunter But does my question make sense atleast? Or am I out of my mind ?

Comment: Avro isn't created for Kafka, instead Avro exists even before Kafka. Avro is released in 2009 and Kafka in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

This article very well explains why serialization is required and where does AVRO comes into play. Also it explains how it differs from textual serialization formats like JSON, XML, CSV etc.

https://devtechfactory.com/blogs/kafka-producer-publish-message-with-avro-schema